Github Workflow and Organization
Is it a good idea to have multiple branchs in github to be representive of multiple subdomains on repo. For example have repo named example respective of example.com and have branch root be for server code for root domain and have a branch auth be server code for auth.example.com. Any thoughts.. Is this a proper use branches on github or will this lead to trouble down the road?
So far I have done this with multiple runners within github and it seems to consolidate the project quite well, however would like to know others thoughts on this as I'm not so sure about industry standards...
All comments are appriciated Thanks!

I think when you only one that used that repo or push code into it, then its helpful for you to create multiple branches for different subdomain in single repository. But when multiple people use that repo or push code that same repo then it does not good practice because at same time need latest code for all. So that time best practice is creates multiple repos for all subdomains so easily multiple people can access and use it and get easily latest code pushed by other team member.
